# Accessing a password protected SQLite database on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, passwords, password-protection

I haven't been able to find a way to open a password-protected SQLite database on Android. Since the device can easily be rooted, I am thinking of password protecting the database file. However, I am not having much luck finding anything built into the Android platform.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Android framework supports password protection on databases. Your best bet is to encrypt your data. See SO question: [Android Sqlite Password Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118793/android-sqlite-password-encryption)

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt SQLiteDatabases. Android does not support full-database encryption so you'd have to implement that yourself if you want to.

If you want to go down the encryption route, you're much better off just encrypting the sensitive information yourself and storing it in a database field, as per Morrison's answer.

All that said -- where are you putting the password for the encryption function? You'll probably need it somewhere in your application! In which case someone can just disassemble your code and  then find the password, and decrypt the info (although it will be a bit more work).

Unless you're hashing info (one-way) then without hardware encryption on a device (and even that has flaws) you cannot store anything on the device perfectly securely -- you're always going to need to decrypt the info some time and for that the password has to be on the device somewhere.

If you want *really* robust security then store sensitive information on a server (preferably in a really secure location), not the device, and only communicate between the device and server over encrypted channels (HTTPS). You'll also need to authenticate the device in a secure manner. But to do that you need to store some sensitive information ON the device in order to authenticate the device with the server, unless you force the user to enter a password every time (recommended if security is a must).
If the information is stored on a server you can't necessarily prevent someone who shouldn't gaining access (by finding the password you have stored or phishing the user if it's stored in their head), but you can revoke access to the information.